# Slicing inside a column

Tags: r, dplyr

I've done slicing within R to separate texts and columns before but having an issue when slicing inside a column. Let's Say I have this data

```
Zip Code <- c("90042 34.11332407100048 -118.19142869099971", 
              "90040 33.99649121800047 -118.15148940099971",
              "90007 34.02833141800045 -118.28507659499968")
```

I want extract just the zip code and place it in a different column. The long/lat will also need to go to another column.

Do I use `grep`?

Comment: `read.table(text=Zip_Code)`

Answer (score 0):

We can use `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
separate(dat, ZipCode, into = c('value', 'lat', 'lon'), sep= ' ')
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#   value              lat                 lon
#* <chr>             <chr>               <chr>
#1 90042 34.11332407100048 -118.19142869099971
#2 90040 33.99649121800047 -118.15148940099971
#3 90007 34.02833141800045 -118.28507659499968
```

#### data

```
dat <- structure(list(ZipCode = c("90042 34.11332407100048   -118.19142869099971", 
"90040 33.99649121800047 -118.15148940099971", "90007 34.02833141800045 -118.28507659499968"
)), .Names = "ZipCode", class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```